# Windows Phone 8 International Assist option: how does it work?

Tags: settings

I found this option in my Lumia 920 in the settings of the Phone app. Can anybody tell me how it works?

I cannot find any good description in the net. Obviously, this phrase from the official page is not enough:

> The International Assist option, which is enabled by default, is
>   designed to automatically correct the most common errors that are made
>   when dialing international numbers.

I'd like to know what rules and when are applied to the numbers I'm trying to dial.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like international assist detects when the **'+'** symbol is needed and can tell when you are missing needed country codes (like 0044) and adds them.

- http://www.pocket-lint.com/news/106669-72-windows-phone-7-tips
- http://www.techradar.com/us/news/phone-and-communications/mobile-phones/25-windows-phone-7-tips-and-tricks-902641
- http://blogs.technet.com/b/next/archive/2011/04/08/hidden-tricks-of-windows-phone-7.aspx#.UzLGjPlSjCc

Comment: Can anybody confirm that or give samples from real life when this worked?

Comment: @TecMan International assist indeed does that. It adds a +91(country code of India) to calls I make within India. The country code is not needed since I am calling within my country. But atleast the call works fine with the country code.

Answer (score -1):

"The International Assist option, which is enabled by default, is designed to automatically correct the most common errors that are made when dialing international numbers."

[The International Assist option](http://www.nokia.com/in-en/support/faq/?action=singleTopic&topic=FA138384)

Comment: Guys, don't place links to those stupid descriptions with "zero value" - better tell me what errors and how are fixed by the system.

Comment: @TecMan. Perhaps you should improve your question to include what details you are looking for. You phrased it in a very generic way.

Comment: @TecMan, If you know something about the thing you're asking, express it in your question. And ask what you really need.

Comment: @NK, it seems I detailed the question as needed. I really do not have any idea of how this option can affect the numbers I'm entering, dialing, etc.

Comment: "international assist" is a misnomer, it's should be "international get things wrong". I have a UK phone and was roaming in Austria. I tried to dial a local number, say 06661234567, by dialling 00436661234567 as one should. The stupid "feature" stripped off the 0043 and then of course the call wouldn't go through. I can find no description of what the feature tries to do. My recommendation is to turn if OFF. It certainly should not be ON by default.